# MPI processor quantity creates error, how to implement broadcast?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle, pi, mpi4py

I have created a python program to calculate pi. I then decided to write it with mpi4py to run with several processes. The program works, but it returns a different value for pi than the original python version. As I looked into this problem more, I found that it returns a less accurate value when I run it with more processors. Why does the MPI version change the result with more processors? Also would it make more sense to use a broadcast rather then sending lots of individual messages? How would I implement broadcast if it is more effective?

MPI version:

```
#!/apps/moose/miniconda/bin/python
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
def f(x):
    return (1-(float(x)**2))**float(0.5)
n = 1000000
nm = dict()
pi = dict()
for i in range(1,size+1):
    if i == size:
        nm[i] = (i*n/size)+1
    else:
        nm[i] = i*n/size
if rank == 0:
    val = 0
    for i in range(0,nm[1]):
        val = val+f(float(i)/float(n))
    val = val*2
    pi[0] = (float(2)/n)*(float(1)+val)
    print name, "rank", rank, "calculated", pi[0]
    for i in range(1, size):
        pi[i] = comm.recv(source=i, tag=i)
    number = sum(pi.itervalues())
    number = "%.20f" %(number)
    import time
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print "Pi is approximately", number
for proc in range(1, size):
    if proc == rank:
        val = 0
        for i in range(nm[proc]+1,nm[proc+1]):
            val = val+f(float(i)/float(n))
        val = val*2
        pi[proc] = (float(2)/n)*(float(1)+val)
        comm.send(pi[proc], dest=0, tag = proc)
        print name, "rank", rank, "calculated", pi[proc]
```

Original Python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
n = 1000000
def f(x):
    return (1-(float(x)**2))**float(0.5)
val = 0
for i in range(n):
    i = i+1
    val = val+f(float(i)/float(n))
val = val*2
pi = (float(2)/n)*(float(1)+val)
print pi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code estimates [image] by computing the area of the quarter of a disk, that is the intergral of [image] using the trapezoidal rule.

The problem of your code is that the ranges of the i values for each process are not complete. Indeed, use a small `n` and print `i` to see what is happening. For instance, `for i in range(nm[proc]+1,nm[proc+1]):` must be changed to `for i in range(nm[proc],nm[proc+1]):`. Otherwise, i=nm[proc] is never handled. 
In addition, in `pi[0] = (float(2)/n)*(float(1)+val)` and `pi[proc] = (float(2)/n)*(float(1)+val)`, the term `float(1)` comes from x=0 in the integral. But it is counted many times, once by each process! As the number of errors varies directly with the number of processes, increasing the number of processes decreases the accuracy, which is the symptom that you have reported.

A broadcast corresponds to a situation where all processes of a communicator must get the same piece of data from a given process. On the contrary, it is here required that data from all processors must be combined using a sum to produce a result available to a single process (called "root"). The latter operation is called a **reduction** and it is performed by `comm.Reduce()`.

Here is a piece of code based on yours using `comm.Reduce()` instead of `send()` and `recv()`.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()
def f(x):
    return (1-(float(x)**2))**float(0.5)

n = 10000000
nm =np.zeros(size+1,'i')

nm[0]=1
for i in range(1,size+1):
    if i == size:
        nm[i]=n
    else:
        nm[i] = (i*n)/size

val=0
for i in range(nm[rank],nm[rank+1]):
    val = val+f((float(i))/float(n))

out=np.array(0.0, 'd')
vala=np.array(val, 'd')
comm.Reduce([vala,MPI.DOUBLE],[out,MPI.DOUBLE],op=MPI.SUM,root=0)
if rank == 0:
    number =(float(4)/n)*(out)+float(2)/n
    number = "%.20f" %(number)
    import time
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print "Pi is approximately", number
```

Comment: Your code is much more accurate and thank you for that. However, I just noticed that when I run it with different numbers of proceses, it returns different results. They are much more accurate, but still different. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: The output with one process is 3.14159265355250161278, while with 2 it is 3.14159265355271211106 and with three it is 3.14159265355250472140

Comment: I also ran it on a large cluster with 10000000000 intervals and 500 processors. This test resulted in 3.95590113700216061687, which seems weird because it should be more accurate with more intervals for the integral.

Comment: For the first errors, my guess is that it is due to the finite precision of python's float, corresponding to double.Indeed more than 13 significant digits is hard to get. The small differences are due to the order of the summation. Regarding the last larger error, 10000000000 is above the limit of 32bit integers: I assume that the error can be attributed to an overflow. Lastly, it is also a large number of additions: studying the floating point errors might be useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130042/minimize-floating-point-error-when-adding-multiple-floating-point-variables